# Lookup spreadsheet values based on a key

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Spreadsheet 1 has student numbers and exam results.

[image: Spreadsheet 1]

Spreadsheet 2 just has the student numbers of everyone in the subject.

[image: Spreadsheet 2]

I need to paste the exam results from Spreadsheet 1 into Spreadsheet 2. However, some students did not participate in the exam (e.g. Student 333333 is in Spreadsheet 2 but not spreadsheet 1).

Ultimately I'd like Spreadsheet 1 to look like this:

[image: Spreadsheet 1 after copy paste]

How can I do this?

The data files are sorted by student number and have 1,000+ entries. About 40 students are in Spreadsheet 2 but missing from Spreadsheet 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In column B, sheet 2, use a VLOOKUP with an IFERROR test that leaves a blank if there is no matching student number.  Cell B2 would be:

```
    =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A$2:B$1000,2,FALSE),"")
```

(Use the actual range.) Copy that down column B.  Any student numbers that are not found on sheet 1 will show as blank.